when runing the LMS template and get an error
When I run the following template：
"Using the LMS Class File"
% A Combined Sample File and Guide for Authors
% This file may be used as a template for writing a paper for submission to the LMS
\def\filedate{20 November 2007}
\def\fileversion{2.1.9}

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\documentclass{lms}
%Include your preferred graphics and mathematics packages here,
%using the command \usepackage{}

%The \newtheorem command is used to define theorem-like environments
%that normally REQUIRE A PROOF, for example:
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section] % 1st argument is your name for it
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}     % 2nd argument is what is printed
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
%To control the numbering sequence of these environments, see
%Lamport's book on LaTeX [2, p. 193].

%The \newnumbered command can be used to define environments or
%independent statements that DO NOT REQUIRE A PROOF. The usual ones are:
\newnumbered{assertion}{Assertion}    % 1st argument is your name for it
\newnumbered{conjecture}{Conjecture}  % 2nd argument is what is printed
\newnumbered{definition}{Definition}
\newnumbered{hypothesis}{Hypothesis}
\newnumbered{remark}{Remark}
\newnumbered{note}{Note}
\newnumbered{observation}{Observation}
\newnumbered{problem}{Problem}
\newnumbered{question}{Question}
\newnumbered{algorithm}{Algorithm}
\newnumbered{example}{Example}
\newunnumbered{notation}{Notation} % This is usually unnumbered
% The numbering sequence of these environments can be controlled in the
% same way as for \newtheorem; see Lamport's book on LaTeX, p. 193.

% The default LMS numbering of equations in long papers is (1.1), (1.2), (2.1), etc.
% In short papers, to change the numbering to (1), (2), etc., 'uncomment' the next line.
% \simpleequations
% Otherwise, use the AMS \numberwithin command.

% TOP MATTER

\title[Title abbreviated to max 50 characters goes here]% end with percent
 {Using the LMS class file} % This is the full title of the paper
% Use lowercase letters in title except for proper names
% Avoid equations in title if possible
% Do not use the \thanks{} command; use \extraline{} instead (see below).

\author{F. Irst, Second Author and T. Hird}

\dedication{A dedication can be included here}

%Insert `2000 Mathematics Subject Classification' numbers here:
\classno{11B83 (primary), 11J71, 37A45, 60G10 (secondary).
 Please refer to {\tt http://www.ams.org/msc/} for a list of codes}

\extraline{Acknowledgements of grants and financial support should
be included here; more general \textsl{Acknowledgements} are better
placed either immediately before the bibliography (see
page~\pageref{ackref}) or at the end of the introduction. Since
author names should not carry footnote marks, instead refer to `The
first author', etc. No `keywords' should be supplied. This guide was
last revised on \filedate\ and documents {\tt lms.cls} version
\fileversion.}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
This is a combined guide and sample {\tt .tex} file for authors
choosing to prepare their papers for the journals of the London
Mathematical Society with the LMS \LaTeXe\ class file. Papers
written in {\tt article.cls} or {\tt amsart.cls} are easily
converted to {\tt lms.cls}, and this can reduce the time to
publication. The LMS class is compatible with commonly used
mathematical packages such as {\tt amsmath}.

An \emph{abstract} written in English is
required and should preferably have fewer than 200 words.
Please do not include citations, footnotes or references
to numbered equations, figures, tables or theorems in your
abstract. Avoid complicated formulae or displayed equations, if
possible.
\end{abstract}

\part{Use this type of header for very long papers only}
% use lowercase except for proper names

\section{Preparation and submission} % use lowercase except for proper names
\label{intro}

\noindent The LMS class file {\tt lms.cls} is distributed with the
following files:
\begin{enumerate}[3]% put widest label, without (), as optional argument.
\item {\tt readme-lms.txt}, {\em notes\/} for unpacking and
      installation;
\item {\tt lms2eau.tex}, a {\em sample file\/} for preparing your
      manuscript;
\item {\tt lms2eau1.ps, lms2eau1.pdf}, the {\em guide\/} `Using
the LMS class file'.
\end{enumerate}
This guide is the printable {\tt .ps} or {\tt .pdf} output
produced from the sample file by the LaTeX or PDFLaTeX compiler,
respectively. The guide displays a number of useful examples but
is by necessity brief. If you cannot find the answer to your query
here, please look in the accompanying file {\tt lms2eau.tex} for
the corresponding \LaTeX\ source code and for further clues, which
are supplied as comment lines beginning with percent signs. It is
convenient to use the sample file as a template from which you can
build your article. Please remember, however, to keep a copy of
the original file {\tt lms2eau.tex} for your reference.

General instructions for the preparation of manuscripts and
submission are available on the web at
\verb"http://www.lms.ac.uk/publications/submission.html".

Please refrain from inserting extra formatting or spaces into your
paper, as this makes the work of the copy-editor more difficult.
Avoid beginning sentences with a mathematical symbol, and do not attach plurals or genitives
to mathematical symbols (such as $D$'s or $D$s). Instead,
insert descriptive nouns where needed before a
mathematical symbol, for example, `the discriminants $D$'.

\begin{note*}% the use of asterisks after statement names is explained below
From 2007 onwards, the journals of the London Mathematical Society
are published in the larger page format demonstrated in these
sample pages.
\end{note*}

\section{Mathematical statements and expressions}

\subsection{Mathematical statements}

Environments for theorems are built into the LMS class file, and
the \verb"amsthm" package should not be used.

Any theorem-like statement that requires a proof (such as
Proposition, Lemma, Theorem or Corollary) must be defined in the
preamble of the {\tt .tex} file using the command
\begin{center}`\verb"\newtheorem{"{\em theoremname}\}\{{\em Printedname}\}'.\end{center}

\begin{theorem}[(Optional argument here {\cite[p.\,193]{Lamport}})]% note the ( ).
\label{mythm}
The string of commands\break`\verb"\begin{"theoremname\verb"}"%
\verb"[(Optional argument here)] "Theorem
text\verb" \end{"theoremname\verb"}"\/'\break produces a numbered
theorem-like statement headed `Printedname'. Please note that\break
parentheses must be included in the optional argument.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem*}
`\/\verb"\begin{"theoremname\verb"*}" Theorem text %
\verb"\end{"theoremname\verb"*}"\/' produces an\break unnumbered
theorem-like statement headed `Printedname'.
\end{theorem*}

Any other independent statement that \emph{does not} require a
proof must be defined in the preamble using the
`\verb"\newnumbered{"{\em statementname}\}\{{\em Printedname}\}'
command. In the next example the argument in square brackets is
optional.

\begin{remark*}[(NB)] %optional argument, note the ( ).
`\verb"\begin{"{\em statementname}\verb"*}[(NB)]" Text
\verb"\end{"{\em statementname}\verb"*}"' produces an unnumbered
independent statement headed `{\em Printedname\/}'.
\end{remark*}

\begin{example}
`\verb"\begin{"{\em statementname}\verb"}" Text \verb"\end{"{\em
statementname}\verb"}"' produces a numbered independent statement
headed `{\em Printedname\/}'.
\end{example}

The numbering sequence of all mathematical statements can be
controlled via options in the \verb"\newtheorem" and
\verb"\newnumbered" commands (see~\cite[p.\,193]{Lamport}).

Two proof statements are predefined in the LMS class. The
\verb"proof" statement ends with a square box, while the
\verb"proof*" statement does not. In the second proof below, we
use the optional argument of the command \verb"\begin{proof*}["of
Theorem\verb"~{\rm\ref{mythm}}]" to refer back to the appropriate
theorem.

\begin{proof}
Here, `\/\verb"\begin{proof}" Proof text \verb"\end{proof}"\/'
produces a proof with a square box marking the end.
\end{proof}

\begin{proof*}[of Theorem~{\rm\ref{mythm}}]
  Using `\verb"proof*"' does not produce a square box.
\end{proof*}

\begin{proof*}[with aligned box] If the proof ends with a single
displayed equation, using \verb"proof*" one should align a square
box with that equation by putting \verb"\singlebox" and
\verb"\esinglebox" as the first and last commands \emph{inside}
the equation, whence
\[ \singlebox
  0.999999\ldots \equiv 1 .
\esinglebox \]
\end{proof*}
If the proof ends with an \verb"eqnarray*" environment, using
\verb"proof*" one should align a square box with the last equation
of the \verb"eqnarray*" environment by \emph{surrounding} that
environment with a pair of \verb"\multbox" and \verb"\emultbox"
commands.

\subsection{Mathematical expressions}

Use \verb"\[" \ldots \verb"\]", \emph{not} \verb"$$" \ldots
\verb"$$", for unnumbered displayed equations. Do not leave blank
lines above and below displayed equations unless a new paragraph
is intended. If the command \verb"\simpleequations" is included in
the preamble, equations will be numbered $(1),(2),(3)\ldots$
instead of $(1.1),(1.2)\ldots$\ .

Bold math italic symbols can be obtained with the command
\verb"\boldsymbol{}", which is part of the \verb"amsbsy" package.
It may also be defined in the preamble as
\[
\verb"\providecommand{\boldsymbol}[1]{\mbox{\boldmath $#1$}}."
\]
Blackboard-bold and \emph{fraktur} symbols can be obtained with
the \verb"\mathbb{}" and \verb"\mathfrak{}" commands, which are
part of the \verb"amssymb" package.

Non-standard functions or mathematical operators that contain more
than one character should be typeset in roman font and should be
defined as a macro using the command \verb"\mathop."
% Let us do this here (should normally go in the preamble):
\providecommand{\Log}{\mathop{\rm Log}\nolimits}%
\providecommand{\Ai}{\mathop{\rm Ai}\nolimits}%
\providecommand{\Bi}{\mathop{\rm Bi}\nolimits}%
\providecommand{\Real}{\mathop{\rm Re}\nolimits}%
\providecommand{\Imag}{\mathop{\rm Im}\nolimits}%
\providecommand{\Arg}{\mathop{\rm Arg}\nolimits}%
\providecommand{\infsup}{\mathop{\rm infsup}}% Note: This one has limits
% Now ready to use them:
Examples of such functions are the principal value of the
logarithm, $\Log$, and the two Airy functions $\Ai$ and $\Bi$;
examples of operators are the real and imaginary parts $\Real$ and
$\Imag$. You may also wish to define something like an
\verb"\infsup" command that takes {\em limits\/} as a subscript
\verb"_{}" and a superscript \verb"^{}". For example, by putting
\begin{eqnarray*}
&~&\verb"\providecommand{\Log}{\mathop{\rm Log}\nolimits},"\\
&~&\verb"\providecommand{\Arg}{\mathop{\rm Arg}\nolimits},"\\
&~&\verb"\providecommand{\infsup}{\mathop{\rm infsup}}"
\end{eqnarray*}
in the preamble, we can easily write (the second example is for
illustration only)
\begin{eqnarray}\label{newdefs}
\Log z = \ln |z| + i \Arg z,\nonumber\\
\infsup_{x\rightarrow 1}{\mathcal B} =
\infsup_{x\rightarrow-1}^{0\leftarrow y}{\mathcal A} = e .
\end{eqnarray}
For single-character mathematical symbols in roman, use \verb"\mathrm{}".

Proper horizontal alignment of indices in a tensorial equation such as
\begin{equation}\label{Riemann}
d\omega_q{}^p - \omega_q{}^s\wedge\omega_s{}^p =
\tfrac{1}{2}R_q{}^p{}_{rs} \omega^r\wedge\omega^s
\end{equation}
can be ensured by inserting a pair of braces \verb"{}" at each vertical
jump:
\begin{eqnarray*}
&~&\verb"d\omega_q{}^p - \omega_q{}^s\wedge\omega_s{}^p ="\\
&~&\verb"\tfrac{1}{2}R_q{}^p{}_{rs} \omega^r\wedge\omega^s"\,.
\end{eqnarray*}

\section{Tables, figures and lists}

As you can see in Table~\ref{mytable}, the LMS class does not
provide vertical side rules on tables. The contents of
Figure~\ref{myfigure} provide detailed information about how one
can incorporate a figure into a paper. Lists generated with
\verb"enumerate" (for a list of short phrases) or \verb"flushenumerate" (for
a\break list of long paragraphs) are preferred. Bullet points should be avoided
if possible.
\begin{table}[b]\vspace*{-3ex}
\caption[]{A small table.} \label{mytable}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\hline
$\alpha$&$\beta$&$\gamma$\\
\hline
1&2&3\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}
% You can include your own figure here using the \includegraphics command,
% or alternatively use the \epsfig, \psfig, or \graphicx packages.
% All lines between here and the \caption statement should then be deleted.
% Use the \vspace command, e.g. \vspace*{5cm}, to leave room for any
% artwork that is provided separately (e.g. as camera-ready copy)
   \vspace*{8pt}%\framebox[8cm][l]{%
   \begin{minipage}{8cm}
   Figures can be inserted with the standard \LaTeXe\ command
   \verb"\includegraphics" (see~\cite{Lamport}), which requires the line
   \verb"\usepackage{graphics}" to be present in the file's preamble.\\
   \hspace*{6pt} You can also use a package such as \verb"\epsfig",
   \verb"\psfig" or \verb"\graphicx". Please use \verb"\epsfig" rather than
   \verb"\epsf", which has become obsolete.\\
   \hspace*{6pt} Please do {\em not\/} incorporate captions into any of
   your {\tt .eps} or {\tt .ps} figure files, but use the \verb"\caption{}"
   command inside the {\tt figure} environment instead.\\
   \hspace*{6pt} If you provide artwork separately, you can leave room for
   it using a \verb"\vspace*{}" command inside the {\tt figure}
   environment.
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace*{8pt}
%
\caption{How to insert a figure.}
\label{myfigure}
\end{figure}

\oneappendix % use \appendix if you have more than one appendix
\section{About the bibliography}
References in the bibliography should be listed alphabetically by
the authors' surname(s) and, for the same set of authors, by
publication year. Detailed formatting (italic, etc.) should be
avoided; please concentrate on giving full and clear information,
such as (for books) the \textit{name} and \textit{location} of the
publisher and (for a book in a book series) the \textit{volume
number}. Do not include papers `in preparation' in the bibliography;
these are better mentioned in the main text only.

\begin{acknowledgements}\label{ackref}
The \verb"acknowledgements" environment may be used to acknowledge
indebtedness to colleagues, host institutions and referees. Accounts
of grants and financial support should be made as a footnote on the
title page using the \verb"\extraline{}" command in the preamble.
\end{acknowledgements}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}% Replace 9 by 99 if 10 or more references
%
% Please note the use of "\and" between author names below
%
\bibitem{Goddard}
{\bibname P. Goddard, A. Kent \and D. I. Olive}, `Unitary
representations of the Virasoro and Supervirasoro algebras', {\em
Comm. Math. Phys. }103 (1986) 105.
%
\bibitem{Lamport}
 {\bibname L. Lamport},
 {\em\LaTeX: A document preparation system {\rm (}updated for
 \LaTeXe{\rm)}} (Addison-Wesley, New York, 1994).
%
\bibitem{Lance}
 {\bibname E. C. Lance \and A. Paolucci},
 `Conjugation in braided C$^*$-categories and
 orthogonal quantum groups',
 {\em J. Math. Phys. }41 (2000) 2383--2394.
%
\bibitem{Stuart}
{\bibname J. T. Stuart}, `Mathematics applied in fluid motion',
{\em Quart. Appl. Math. }56 (1998) 787--796.
%
\bibitem{PRL}
 {\bibname
T.~Prokopec, O.~T\"ornkvist \and R.~P.~Woodard}, `Photon mass
  from inflation', \emph{Phys. Rev. Lett. }89 (2002) 101301.
\end{thebibliography}

\affiliationone{% in this example, two authors share an institution
   F. Irst and Second Author\\
   Postal Address should be
      added here, including\\
   Country
   \email{first@university.ac.uk\\
   sauthor@university.ac.uk}}
% Important: Do not put any empty line here.
\affiliationtwo{% in this example, one author has two addresses}
   T. Hird\\
   Previous postal address where
     the research was performed and\\
   Country
   \email{hird@university.ac.uk}}
% Important: Do not put any empty line here.
% Use \affiliationthree{} for any address positioned under \affiliationone
% Use \affiliationfour{}  for any address positioned under \affiliationtwo
\affiliationthree{~} %inserts a space to make this field empty
\affiliationfour{%
   Current address:\\
   Present long-term address\\
   Country
   \email{t.hird@institution.edu}}
%
\end{document}

The output is as follows:
! Undefined control sequence.
1.7 \\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

How to solve the problem

I tried again. The output is :"Using the LMS Class File". It does not work.

also give a link to lms.cls (I thnk you did in a previous question but it helps to make the question self contained)

The output is as above: see the screenshot.

The first line of the template should be a comment, so % "Using the LMS Class File".  But I don't think this style is maintained anymore.  It is not available from the London Mathematical Society's website and their submission instructions do not refer to it.

@AndrewSwann, yes, I cannot find the file. I am afraid that the length of my article does not meet the standard. So I need to run the LMS template to check the pages of the article.

@David Carlisle I need to run the LMS template to check the pages of the article.

I suggest you write to the LMS and ask for guidance.  Yes there is a link suggesting that you compile with that package, but the link to package points to newer instructions, and class file.

@AndrewSwann I have written an email but have not received a response.

@David Carlisle. I tried to download the class file from the LMS’s website. But I cannot find the file.

@mathbeginner There is no reason at all to think that LMS use a LaTeX class, or support one for submissions - their website makes no mention. Short of information from the editorial office, I'm not sure what else there is to say.

As far as can be seen the London Mathematical Society no longer distributes or uses the lms class and there is no reason to use it in a new document however there is still a copy available from an lms template at overleaf
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-journal-of-the-london-mathematical-society-lms/rggmkdznnsbj
If you use lms.cls  from that template and restore the % missing from the first line comment of the document in your question.
%     "Using the LMS Class File"

then the posted document runs without error with pdflatex and produces a 4 page pdf


Thank you very much.

I tried again. Still have an error. ! Latex Error:File ‘lms.cls’ not found.

@mathbeginner as I say you can get lms.cls from the overleaf template and save it next to the document.  Where did you get that template document from, the lms.cls would have been available from the same place. But it doesn't matter anyway there is no reason to use this at all.
